# Enabling USB OTG on Samsung Galaxy Y Duos

Tags: samsung-galaxy-y-duos, usb-on-the-go

I am planning to develop an Android application which uses [USB On-The-Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go).

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Y Duos. Is there any way that I can enable USB OTG in this phone?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enable **USB OTG** on **Samsung Galaxy Y Duos**. Thats all I know so far.

Comment: Any reference to claim your points?

Comment: I've searched a lot for that, because I also have the same phone. and I found nothing yet.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that it is a hardware ability in phones which should provide electricity for USB devices to run. Also most of the Sony phones support it but few Samsungs devices. I have a Galaxy Young.

By the way, I now see [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1567203). The new developer claims the Young is an O.T.G device ... I hope so.

Comment: by the way now I see this page .. the new developer claims the young is an O.T.G device ... I hope it [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1567203](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1567203)